# Check Task.Run Is Not Already Running

Tags: c#, asynchronous

How can I check if a process running under *Task.Run* as bellow is already running?

```
private async void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){ 
    //check goes here - abort if running 
    await Task.Run(() =>  myMath.Calculate() );
}
```

Comment: you can keep tracking the task's `ID` in a global variable for example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Task.Run()` method returns a `Task` object. You can, instead of immediate using `await` with it, assign the `Task` object reference to a variable, which you can then use later to check its status.

For example:

```
private Task _task;

private async void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){ 
    //check goes here - abort if running 
    if (_task != null && !_task.IsCompleted)
    {
        // Your code here -- use whatever mechanism you deem appropriate
        // to interrupt the Calculate() method, e.g. call Cancel() on
        // a CancellationToken you passed to the method, set a flag,
        // whatever.
    }

    Task task = Task.Run(() =>  myMath.Calculate());
    _task = task;
    await _task;
    if (task == _task)
    {
        // Only reset _task value if it's the one we created in this
        // method call
        _task = null;
    }
}
```

Note that the above is a bit awkward. It's possible that there is a better mechanism for dealing with an already-running task in your scenario. But given the broadly stated requirement, I think the above is a reasonable approach.

Comment: is it possible for this code to start two tasks if the user clicks quickly? I was thinking some synchronization might be required.

Comment: @NedStoyanov: one of the advantages of using `async`/`await` is that the event handler code itself can only execute in a single thread, making it inherently synchronized. If the user clicks quickly, the second time the event handler is called, the first execution of the handler will have already assigned the `_task` variable, allowing the "cancel previously started task" logic (i.e. the part you asked how to do) to work.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, actually the question is mine ;). I like how looks your code and it seems to fulfill my needs, I'm testing and Ill let you know. +1

Comment: @Elio.Batista: ah, sorry for the mixup. I do that often enough you'd think I'd double-check to whom I'm replying. :) My apologies for the confusion! Glad to hear the code looks good to you...I hope it addresses your need.